# navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia not working while navigator.getUserMedia() works

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, getusermedia

I know there are several posts on this, but my question is different.

Following the [Mozilla developer guide for getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia), I can see that using: `navigator.getUserMedia()` is deprecated:

> New code should use Navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia() instead.

However, using Chrome (current version 57), `navigator.getUserMedia()` works great, while using `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` throws an error:

> navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(...) is not a function

I am using HTTPS with Chrome.

Is it really deprecated? Am I missing something?

Comment: Cannot reproduce https://plnkr.co/edit/LLRULhcH5tIvIvKCIZuh?p=preview. Can you include full `javascript` tried at Question?

Comment: Do you have any plugin that could modify `navigator.mediaDevices` ? Chrome does support the new mediaDevices.gUM API (since 53)

Comment: @Kaiido - I remember you from previous answers :)  -- No I use a pretty much classic javascript

Comment: Yes, I'm often around questions about gUM and MediaStreams raising at this time of the day ;-) And by plugin I don't mean a js library, but a browser plugin, like some privacy shield extension taht could disable some features of the browser.

Comment: @Kaiido  plugins... I have: Cisco Webex, and Stylish

Comment: Try disabling these and retry. (Cisco Webex is my favorite suspect).

Comment: @Kaiido You the man. Please post this as an aswer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome does support `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` API since version 53.

From the discussion we had in comments, we were able to determine that this was caused by a **browser plugin** you have installed on your chrome, namely Cisco Webex.

This video-conference plugin might modify the default `navigator.mediaDevices` object.
 <sub>which is wrong ! You should probably write to them about this issue.</sub>

By disabling this plugin you'll be able to retrieve the original and well supported method in your chrome browser.